# Is it possible to delete an object from inside its own function? [Python]

Tags: python, class, oop, del

I was wondering if I could delete an object from inside its own function. Here's what I'm thinking:

```
class ball:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def update(self, t):
        if t >= self.a:
            del self # Need help here

myBall = ball(120)

for i in range(0, 1000):
    myBall.update(i)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293431/python-object-deleting-itself

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the loop gets to `myBall.update(121)`?

Comment: Why would you even want to do this?

Comment: @poke wouldn't it save memory if at a certain point where an object is no longer needed, I delete it. (This code was just for example's sake)

Comment: But how can an object itself determine if it’s still needed by something else? It can only look at itself, so there’s no way to have that knowledge about other things.

Answer (score 0):

`del self` is just deleting the reference, not the actual object.

`self` is a reference to your object.